# Is it okay to filter firebase data using conditions? Will it affect the speed and accuracy of Firebase realtime database?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-realtime-database

Example:

```
final String campus = "BISU Calape";

private ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {       
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        
        facultyList.clear();

        for(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()){
            Faculty faculty = dataSnapshot.getValue(Faculty.class);
            faculty.setKey(dataSnapshot.getKey());
            if(faculty.getCampus().equals(campus) && faculty.getMemStatus.equals("Approved")){
                facultyList.add(faculty);
            }
        }

        if(facultyList.size() > 0){
            tv_noresult.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }else{
            tv_noresult.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
        Toast.makeText(FacultyActivity.this, error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
};
```

This code is working so far, but what if this code will have to fetch/filter millions of records?

Comment: Did you see the documentation on sorting and filtering data: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#sorting_and_filtering_data?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I have seen the documentation but I want to query based on multiple where clauses in Firebase

Comment: Hey Vince. What do you mean by "filter firebase data using conditions"? What are the exact conditions? Please respond using @AlexMamo

Comment: @AlexMamo I want to get all members whose campus="BISU Main Campus" and member status="Approved"..I have already used orderByChild for searching members based on their Full Name

Comment: Firebase Database queries can only order/filter on a single property. In many cases it is possible to combine the values you want to filter on into a single (synthetic) property. For an example of this and other approaches, see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26700924/query-based-on-multiple-where-clauses-in-firebase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Firebase Realtime Database doesn't support queries on multiple properties. It supports only queries on a single child property. There is however a workaround in which you can create a new field in the database that can hold both values:

```
Firebase-root
   |
   ---- faculties
         |
         --- $campusId
                |
                --- campus: "BISU Main Campus"
                |
                --- status: "Approved"
                |
                --- campus_status: "BISU Main Campus_Approved"
```

So as you see, the `campus_status` field combines the values that you want to filter on.

So now, the following query will work:

```
DatabaseReference db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference facultiesRef = db.child("faculties");
Query queryByCampusAndStatus = facultiesRef.orderByChild("campus_status").equalTo("BISU Main Campus_Approved");
```

Unlike the Realtime database, [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/) allows [compound queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#compound_queries). This means that you can use multiple `whereEqualTo()` calls. So a query like the one below it will work perfectly fine:

```
facultiesRef.whereEqualTo("campus", "BISU Main Campus").whereEqualTo("status", "Approved");
```

Comment: I think I should use Firestore now. Thanks!

Comment: Good luck with that. If have a hard time implementing something, please post a new question here, on StackOverflow, so I or other Firebase developers can help you.